# SWIG/Lua typemap for Boost Array in

Tags: c++, boost, lua, swig

I am trying to build a typemap(in) for use with C++ boost scoped_arrays. I have C++ functions which take the boost arrays, but I'd like to pass them Lua lists.

I have seen examples for Python, but they seem to contain too much Python-specific code.

Has anyone got help or pointers to an example to get me started?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use something like:

```
%{
#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>
%}

namespace boost {

template<class T>
class scoped_array {
public:
    scoped_array();
    ~scoped_array();

    void reset();
    void swap(scoped_array& b);

    %extend
    {
        scoped_array(unsigned n)
        {
            return new scoped_array<T>(new T[n]);
        }
        T __getitem__(unsigned int idx)
        {
            return (*self)[idx];
        }
        void __setitem__(unsigned int idx,T val)
        {
            (*self)[idx]=val;
        }
    };
};

}
```

as a starting point. It exposes the important bits of [`boost::scoped_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) and is based loosely on the `std::vector` implementation that SWIG has in its standard typemap library.

It adds special member functions and a new constructor which also allocates some storage at the same time. It doesn't show some of the definition to SWIG because I couldn't see a use for them in your target language.

Note: I've *not* compiled and checked this. SWIG is happy with it and the generated wrapper looks sane.

Comment: How would you proceed to achieve the same result using a plain float array? (to set and get the item I mean)

Comment: Im basically trying to do the same thing as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724937/lua-swig-set-get-float-array?lq=1